# System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]

Tags: apex-email-service

I have written a class to send sms. I am using core-visa api to send sms. But when I execute this code, but in debug log I could see  this error:

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]

```
global class corevisa_sms_api 
{           



        global void sendsms()
        {
            String username = 'JRjNX4xr0yQDTnyuoitgv' ;
            String password = 'vyAK$ja7NhLOcI8pX34lokMxUiuytrfvv.i';
            String message= 'Hi this msg. is for testing of "sending msg.on mobile when SLA breach"';
             HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://api.us1.corvisa.io/sms/send');
            req.setMethod('POST'); 
            String phonenumber='+15123355101';
            //String body='{"text":"  '+message+'","to_number":"'+phoneNumber+'"}';
            //String body='{"text": "Test Message","to_number": "+15123355101"}';
            //String body='{"messages"":""Hi this is for test","to_number"":" "+15123355101"}';
            String body='{"messages": [{"text":  "text of message","to_number": "+15123355101"}]}';
            Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
            String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' +  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
                 req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
                 req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
                 HTTPResponse res= new HTTPResponse();
                 req.setBody(body); 
                 Http http = new Http();
                 //res.setStatusCode(200);
                 res = http.send(req);
                 system.debug(res.toString());
        }

}
```

Comment: 0) Triple check credentials and endpoint
1) Double check format of request based on corsiva documentations
2) Get a message that your code is trying to send and test it via curl (or postman)
3)Ensure that posted credentials are are not **real**. if somehow they are -- delete post and reset them ASAP

Comment: Yes, you should not post valid credentials under any circumstances. You can also get more useful information by debugging `res.getBody()`.